# Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil in X mode

Tags: evil, debugging

I'm getting a strange error on Emacs 27. Only in GUI mode (not in terminal mode), typing `/` to open the Evil search functionality results in the error `wrong type argument: arrayp, nil` being displayed in the echo area.

Comment: `M-: (setq debug-on-error t)` and repeat the command, it should give you a backtrace that will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Emacs 27 has not been released. Please specify the build info for your development snapshot, to help others help you.